# I am having trouble with resetting the counter in jquery (clickfunction)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I am trying to repeat the clickfunction but it will only repeat twice. After that the counter disappears. I don't know what the cause of this is. H

```js
var divClone = $("#target").clone();
var divClone = $("#output").clone();

var clickCount = 0;
$('#target').click(function() {
    if ( clickCount < 6){
    clickCount++;
    $('#output').html(function(i, val) { return val*1+1 });
    } else {
      clickCount = 0; 
     $("#output").replaceWith(divClone);
    }
    
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="target" type="button">Click Me</button>
<div id="output">0</div>
```

Note that I am quite new to programming.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Sorry, I don't want it to be automatic. After every 6 clicks the counter should reset to zero.

Comment: Sorry, I don't want it to be automatic. After every 6 clicks the counter should reset to zero.

Comment: You could do with `var count = 0; $('#target').click(function() {  $('#output').html(count++ < 6 && count || ( count = 0 )); });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

http://jsfiddle.net/zRX2D/2707/

```
var clickCount = 0;
$('#target').click(function() {
    if ( clickCount < 6){
    clickCount++;

    } else {
      clickCount = 0; 
    }
    $('#output').html(clickCount);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var clickCount = 0;
$('#target').click(function() {
    if (clickCount++ < 6) {
        $('#output').html(function(i, val) {
            return val * 1 + 1
        });
    } else {
        clickCount = 0;
        $('#output').html('0');
    }
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/zRX2D/2708/

**OR**

Simple:

```
var clickCount = 0;
$('#target').click(function () {
    $('#output').html(++clickCount % 7);
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/zRX2D/2711/

Answer (score 0):

Check following:

```js
var clickCount = 0;
$('#target').click(function() {
    clickCount = clickCount < 6 ? clickCount+=1 : 0;
       
     $("#output").text(clickCount);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="target" type="button">Click Me</button>
<div id="output">0</div>
```